# How to change img src string from ending with _m to _t using jquery for a set of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was hoping to get a nice push in the right direction I would like to change the ending of my images sources string... i hope i worded that right.

Anyway my current src's are reading:

```
<img src="something/something/12345_m.jpg" />
```

I would like to change it to:

```
<img src="something/something/12345_t.jpg" />
```

Any idea guys...Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one is a bit safer:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace(/_m(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_t$1');
});
```

Else you may risk URL's like `/bat_man/images/oh_my_god_m.png` to end up as `/bat_tan/images/oh_my_god_m.png` when using eKek0's answer.

---

Explanation of the regex `/_m(\.[^.]+)?$/`:

- `/.../` are just pattern borders.
- `_m` matches literal `_m`.
- `(...)` match grouping, the first one ends as `$1` in result.
- `\.` matches literal `.`. Because `.` is a special char in regex, it's escaped by `\`.
- `[...]` represents group of characters.
- `^.` matches everything **but** literal `.`. Because it's inside a group, escaping is not needed.
- `+` matches one or more characters.
- `?` previous group is optional (for the case that there's no file extension).
- `$` match must occur at end of string (and thus not in the middle or so).

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket on attr

Answer (score 1):

```
$(img).each(function () {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).attr('src', src.replace("_m", "_t");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery on this one:

```
function argsToArray(args) {
  var r = []; for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    r.push(args[i]);
  return r;
}
argsToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).forEach(function(img) {
  img.src = img.src.split('_m').join('_t');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`img.src = "<image source>";` where the `img` variable is searched from the DOM like this: `document.getElementByTagName('img')[0]` or this: `document.getElementById('image')` (if `<img id="image" />`), learn about the HTML DOM to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace(/_m\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/, '_t.$1'));
});
```